# 'state' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm really new to react, but I wanted to render the 'College' component only for each state I input in the 'Input' bar. I'm getting the above error. Am I filtering the rendering portion wrong? Thanks for helping a newbie :)

```
import College from './College';

const Home = (props) => {

  const [colleges, setColleges] = useState([
    {name: 'Princeton', price: 1100.00, img: Princeton, tag: 'princeton'},
    {name: 'Stanford', price: 1100.00, img: Stanford, tag: 'stanford'},
    {name: 'Brown', price: 1100.00, img: Brown, tag: 'brown'},
    {name: 'Columbia', price: 1100.00, img: Columbia, tag: 'columbia'},
    {name: 'Wake', price: 1100.00, img: Wake, tag: 'wake'},
    {name: 'Ross', price: 1100.00, img: Ross, tag: 'ross'},
  ])
   const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
   const renderColleges = (colleges) => (colleges.map(colleges => <College {...colleges} />))

  return (

    <div>

      <Row align="middle" className='title'>
        <Input placeholder="Search for a school" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} value={search}/>
      </Row>

      <Row align="middle" className='container'>
        {renderColleges(state.colleges.filter(search))}
      </Row>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're using classes, you have an object `state` and `colleagues` will be in it obviously.

But when you use useState hook, `colleagues` itself is the state property and `setColleagues` is its setter (setState), and you need not write `state.colleagues`, just use `colleagues`.

So you need to use `{renderColleges(colleges.filter(search))}`. But you have an issue in filtering too. It should be something like this. `{renderColleges(state.colleges.filter(c => c.name.includes(search))}`

Comment: This is a great answer! On the other hand when using `Array.prototype.func` please visit MDN for more information and useful examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/